# What's the optimal way to get a list of buffers containing real files?

Tags: vim

In my Vimscript I would like to iterate over all/only the buffers containing files on disk.  At the moment I'm doing this to get an array of buffer ids:

`filter(range(1, bufnr('$')), 'buflisted(v:val)')`

And then later on I test each buffer id with:

`filereadable(fnamemodify(bufname(buffer_id), ':p'))`

I've read the documentation on buflisted, bufloaded, and friends, but I'm still not clear what the difference is between them.  Consequently I'm not sure whether my snippet above is optimal.

Furthermore this seems a common task for which there would be a built-in function, but I can't find one.

Is this the best way or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

I guess the "common way" is just using `:bufdo` and have it fail on `:write` of unnamed, unpersisted files, but in a plugin, it's good to do more checking.

Your approach looks fine to me. `:help 'buflisted'` says:

> If it is reset it is not used for ":bnext", "ls", the Buffers menu, etc.
>   This option is reset by Vim for buffers that are only used to remember
>   a file name or marks.  Vim sets it when starting to edit a buffer.

So assuming your plugin does something similar to `:bufdo`, using `buflisted()` is right.

Comment: OK, but with `buflisted()` I believe I still need the second test I wrote which calls three functions per buffer.  It's not efficient.

Comment: The second test (which you could roll into the first `filter()`) checks for _existing files_. Yes, you need that if that's part of your criteria.

Comment: Overall performance is most impacted by the file name expansion and file system checks, not by calling three functions; though you'd need to profile to know for sure. Don't worry about that until you're actually running into problems. Only then tackle the real bottleneck, not what you perceive to be slow.

Comment: I am indeed running into performance problems – hence this question.  And I know what the second test does, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think the buffer_id -> filename conversion can be done better by:

```
expand('#' . buffer_id . ':p')
```

This could be combined with the buffer list into this one-liner:

```
filter(range(1, bufnr('$')), 'buflisted(v:val) && filereadable(expand("#" . v:val . ":p"))')
```